# Positioning gameobject from canvas to a 3D gameobject (Unity 3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie in Unity, I can't figure out how to get the position of 3D `GameObject` relative to the Camera or the Canvas.

I know that `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(target)` can be used to get the position of a `GameObject`. Is there a way to get the Position of a `GameObject` on Camera View or Canvas?

I have already made an alternative solution by just

- Moving the image outside the Canvas.
- Creating a Blind Image positioned on Target 3D `GameObject`.

But I don't like both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently spent some time with this very problem.  My intention was to position a 2D arrow over a 3D world object and found using `Camera.WorldToViewportPoint()` and `RectTransform.anchorMin/Max` to be the best solution.

Note that *viewpoint point* is normalized (`0.0 - 1.0`) and not an absolute pixel position:

```
Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(someObject.transform.position);
arrowImage.rectTransform.anchorMin = screenPos;
arrowImage.rectTransform.anchorMax = screenPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the game object's position projected onto the canvas, use below code:

```
var pos = gameObject.transform.position;
var vec2 = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(camera, pos);
Debug.Log(vec2);
```

[image]

In another case, if you want to get the screen coordinate of a UI-game object, try below:

```
public static List<Vector2> GetScreenCoordinateOfUIRect(RectTransform rt)
{
    Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
    rt.GetWorldCorners(corners);

    var output = new List<Vector2>();
    foreach (Vector3 item in corners)
    {
        var pos = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(null, item);
        output.Add(pos);
    }
    return output;      
}
```

In this way, you can get the screen points of a UI game object (who has a RectTransform component), with bottom left as origin. Note that this screen point is independent of the anchor points, in all anchor point settings, this function works!

Comment: You haven't shown how to position the 2D object, and when you do you will probably find that it doesn't work.  I know, as I have been through this myself.

Comment: how to position the 2D object? Mind clarify what you mean?

Comment: Well I am assuming the OP wants the position on the UI so that he can place a 2d sprite at that position.  That part of the problem is not trivial.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the so called "GameObject" in the OP. If this refers to the UI game object, of course, this is a different story, but I think the OP means non-UI (3D) game object.

Comment: MyObj.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(NonUIGameObj.transform.position);  "WorldToScreenPoint" is just what I need. thank u.

Comment: Sorry for your misunderstandings. But its clear enough that the UIGameObject was within the hierarchy of the Canvas. And I was really pertaining to a non-UI GameObject which was called World Object in unity.